# dotnet core odbc vertica with Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, odbc, vertica

I have a dotnet core application that connects to Vertica using ODBC `System.Data.Odbc`. When I run it from my windows machine on Visual Studio it runs fine. But I want to containerize it and run it on a Linux server, I am getting the below error:

> exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.ODBC is not supported on this platform.
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection..ctor(String connectionString)

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0.1-buster-slim

# ODBC driver manager
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-bin \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Vertica ODBC driver and configurations
RUN curl https://www.vertica.com/client_drivers/9.3.x/9.3.0-0/vertica-client-9.3.0-0.x86_64.tar.gz | 
tar xz opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so opt/vertica/en-US/VerticaMessages.xml opt/vertica/en- 
US/ODBCMessages.xml

COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/
COPY vertica.ini /etc/

COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/publish/ /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Loader.dll"]
```

I also tried the below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
```

instead of

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0.1-buster-slim`
```

but with the same error.
Below is my odbinst.ini:

```
[Vertica]
Description = Vertica driver
Driver   = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so
Driver64 = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so
```

Below is my vertica.ini:

```
[Driver]
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
ODBCInstLib = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/vertica/lib64
LogLevel=4
LogPath=/tmp
```

Here's how I'm opening a connection in my application:

```
_odbcConn = new OdbcConnection(pConnectionString);
```

My connectionstring:

```
Driver={Vertica};Server=192.168.109.1;Port=5433;Database=testdb;UID=dbadmin;PWD=test
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have you tried using .NET Core 3.1?  It looks like you're using .NET Core 3.0 which has been out of support since March 2020.

Comment: no I also tried `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime` but with the same error